# Entity Framework Core's AddRangeAsync() doesn't work in a generic method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This works:

```
await AddRangeAsync(myEntities);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
await AddEntities(myEntities);
```

...when I try to use this function:

```
private async Task AddEntities<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    await AddRangeAsync(entities);
}
```

I get an error: `"The entity type 'List<MyType>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model."`

This is a part of a larger abstraction effort I'm making. Why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is yet another example of `params object[]` trap.

`AddRangeAsync` has two overloads:

(1)

```
Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<object> entities, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

(2)

```
Task AddRangeAsync(params object[] entities)
```

I assume you want to call the (1), but the question is - which one is actually called here:

```
private async Task AddEntities<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    await AddRangeAsync(entities);
}
```

The answer is - it depends!

If `T` has `class` constraint, it will call (1), otherwise (2). This is because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant only for reference types, so it could be treated as `IEnumerable<object>` only if compiler knows that `T` is reference type, which is achieved with `class` constraint.

Looks like your class has not such constraint, so the compiler treats `IEnumerable<T>` argument as `object` (everything can be cast to `object`) and calls the (2), passing single item `object` array with the argument, i.e. the actual call in this case is

```
await AddRangeAsync(new object[] { entities });
```

which should demystify the error message.

With that being said, either use `where T : class` constraint, or `Cast` extension method:

```
await AddRangeAsync(entities.Cast<object>());
```